# 2020 Potential Moderator Election: Community Interest Check

Tags: discussion, election

It's time for us to consider holding an election for moderators for Ask Ubuntu.

The last election we held was back in 2019, where we elected a single moderator, and since then, several of our moderators have resigned (Seth, terdon, jrg, and RolandiXor). That leaves us with fewer moderators than we had, and of that not all of us are active.

So: we should hold a new election to get ourselves back up to a more regularly-available and active moderation team. To avoid finding ourselves in a situation where an election would fail due to an insufficient number of candidates, though, I'm posting this to try to assess the community members' willingness to step up and nominate themselves, when the actual election's nomination period starts.

Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position, should we decide to run an election.

NOTE: This is **not** an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up.

Currently, June 1st is the tentative date for such an election, but only if we can get enough people willing to run for moderator positions.

**A moderator election [has been scheduled](https://askubuntu.com/election/7) for June 1st.  The Question Collection post is now up [here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19104/306823).**

Comment: lt would help if there is something related to what this envolves. How much time you for instance spent on AU as a moderator. How you divide your time.

Comment: also Rolandixor is still a moderator.

Comment: @Rinzwind he has the diamond, but posted on meta last month that he'll be stepping down soon (and hasn't been all that active before that). For practical purposes, I'd say he's not around as a mod anymore.

Comment: How many candidates would we need for an election not to fail?

Comment: I retire at the end of this year so perhaps in 2021 :)

Comment: So, how is this looking? There are some good candidates but is it enough? I guess more will run on the day if they don't read meta. Should some of us run just to make up the numbers? I don't want the site to be too low on mods.

Comment: What about the rest of the mostly inactive mods that aren't providing any value to the site? Personally, I think they should be replaced with new blood. All four of these respondents seem to have an active interest in maintaining the quality of the site. There are a couple that I don't see providing much value.

Comment: @KevinBowen A good portion of the *existing* mod team are indeed online and active but not in the forefront of the site operations like I am.  Just because you don't *see* the mods doing things doesn't mean they aren't inactive, there's several ways of tracking activity of mods that aren't visible to the rest of the site and users.  Hence why we're going to be running an election to get 2 more people soon.

Comment: @MarkKirby https://askubuntu.com/election/7

Answer (score 30):

I would be willing to stand again if there were an election :)

Comment: Glad to see throw your hat in the ring. I think you would make a great addition to the mod squad.

Answer (score 17):

I would like to join the existing crew.

Answer (score 17):

Well, I have run in the past two elections and I would run again.

Answer (score 13):

I have the time, and would be happy to serve.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your interest. For your information, the [nomination phase](https://askubuntu.com/election) is ending tomorrow and you have to nominate yourself to partake in the election.

Comment: Hello, how do I nominate myself

Answer (score -2):

I would love to continue to help people in this community! I've been on a pause due to my personal offline circumstances once - sadly, it was too deep to evade, but I'm online and I do have both: a desire to help and a time to do so. So - I'll be glad to continue serving this community to make things safer!

Comment: Btw this was a post from 2020, we did end up having [a moderator election](https://askubuntu.com/election/7) after that. I'm not sure if we need more moderators now. If I understood the process correctly, that's up to the current moderators to decide if they are overloaded and need more moderators help.

Comment: Don't worry - There's plenty you can (and should) do to help the site while you gain the experience needed to (maybe, eventually) be a Mod.  For now, and for starters, you should start by building your rep here on Ask Ubuntu by asking and answering good questions (on the main site, not necessarily Meta).