# Suggestion to change description of "End of Support" / "End of Life" in Help Center

Tags: discussion, help-center

I would suggest the following change to the Help Center page on "[What topics to ask](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)", under the last bullet in "Questions you should avoid":

- Support for Ubuntu releases [past their "End of Standard Support" or "End of Life" dates](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) (whichever is earlier) — unless the question is asking how to upgrade to a supported release.

Is changed to:

- Support for Ubuntu releases [past their support period](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)  (5 years after first release for LTS and 9 months after first release for non-LTS) — unless the question is asking how to upgrade to a supported release

This is not taking into account a different support timespan for Ubuntu Core though.

Alternate suggestion if Ubuntu Core support is 10 years (as it currently appears to be - [pending clarification](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1361838/whats-the-official-support-period-for-ubuntu-core-releases)):

- Support for Ubuntu releases [past their support period](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)  (10 years after first release for Core, 5 years after first release for LTS and 9 months after first release for non-LTS) — unless the question is asking how to upgrade to a supported release

This would in my opinion make the paragraph more precise and easier to understand. And there would be no doubt, that there's up to 3 time frames you should know for a release to expire here - 10 years (Core), 5 years (LTS) and 9 months (non-LTS).

The way it's phrased right now, if I was a new reviewer, and hadn't read the [meta post](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19616/how-long-do-we-support-ubuntu-flavors), I would assume the on-topic period is 5 years for standard Ubuntu and 3 years for official flavors. In addition, the current guidelines do not mention Ubuntu Core at all.

Comment: I disagree with this solely on the fact that specific 'text' links to the Ubuntu Releases list which includes the specific dates.  Is there a reason that you want us to be extra verbose rather than suggest to users they check the actual dates/releases on the Ubuntu wiki and use the official dates there instead of ballparking it themselves?

Comment: There's nothing factually wrong with the current text, but I simply believe it is more likely to be misunderstood.

Comment: Do not see how the change would help or hurt anything so why do it?

Comment: @guiverc do you have an opinion here? I can see you state in [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1364875/data-partition-no-longer-accessible#comment2342708_1364875) that Ubuntu Core is 10 years support, but off-topic here. How do you come to that conclusion when Ubuntu Core is not mentioned in the Help Center at all?