# End of Life Notice: Ubuntu 21.04 (Hirsute Hippo) reached End of Life on January 20, 2022

Tags: discussion, scope, end-of-life

> This will be enforced starting from January 20, 2022 and onwards.

This is a notice regarding releases of Ubuntu that will be reaching, or have reached, the end of their standard support period.  These releases are no longer on topic effective the above enforcement date.

The following version of Ubuntu and its derivatives **officially reached End of Standard Support** on January 22, 2022:

- Hirsute Hippo (21.04)

New questions specific to the above versions of Ubuntu posted on or after the enforcement date may need to be considered **offtopic**.  Old questions (before the end of standard support date) that are still being answered regarding these releases should have a comment included on them about upgrading to a supported release to get continued support for their versions of Ubuntu.

This information can be confirmed via the **[End of Life Announcement for 21.04 on the Ubuntu Announce mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2022-January/000276.html).** (this was sent out on **January 20, 2022**).

Per discussions related to scope and on-topic posts [effective April 12, 2021](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19575/policy-clarifications-in-place-on-end-of-standard-support-and-end-of-life?cb=1), End of Standard Support and End of Life are treated the same way with posts becoming 'Offtopic' at that point.

> If you have a concern with this policy, raise it as a separate Meta issue.  DO NOT post to this thread regarding your concerns with how we handle end of standard support and end of life posts.

Comment: I got busy this week and didn't make this notice - now I did.  This was effective starting January 20th.