# End of Life Notice: Ubuntu 21.10 (Impish Indri) reached End of Life on July 14, 2022

Tags: discussion, scope, end-of-life

> This will be enforced starting from July 14, 2022 and onwards.

This is a notice regarding releases of Ubuntu that will be reaching, or have reached, the end of their life cycle.  These releases are no longer on topic effective the above enforcement date.

The following version of Ubuntu and its derivatives **officially reached End of Life** on July 14, 2022:

- Impish Indri (21.10)

New questions specific to the above versions of Ubuntu posted on or after the enforcement date may need to be considered **offtopic**.  Old questions (before the end of standard support date) that are still being answered regarding these releases should have a comment included on them about upgrading to a supported release to get continued support for their versions of Ubuntu.

This information can be confirmed via the **[End of Life Announcement for 21.10 on the Ubuntu Announce mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2022-May/000280.html)** (this notice been sent on May 31, 2022 to the announcements list)

Per discussions related to scope and on-topic posts [effective April 12, 2021](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19575/policy-clarifications-in-place-on-end-of-standard-support-and-end-of-life?cb=1), End of Standard Support and End of Life are treated the same way with posts becoming 'Offtopic' at that point.

> If you have a concern with this policy, raise it as a separate Meta issue.  DO NOT post to this thread regarding your concerns with how we handle end of standard support and end of life posts.

Comment: Day late to posting, but my Internet exploded Wednesday and I was still rebuilding it yesterday.